# process.cwd() in vscode extension debugging mode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing a vscode extension.
In the all of places of the project (src and dependencies) `process.cwd()` returns the path of the extension (instead of the project that I run the extension on)

For example, this is a function in my extension:

```
export function playGame() {
  console.log(process.cwd());
}
```

When I run the extension with F5 it returns me
`/home/me/path-of-extension`
but it should return
`home/me/game-project`

Is there any way to change `process.cwd()` to the project path? I know I can do it with `process.chdir()` but I couldn't run `process.chdir()` in start of extension

Comment: Several red flags. 1) Try to use VS Code logging API to write logs, not `console.log`. 2) As extensions are hosted in separate processes, so `process` has its own meaning and its `cwd` can be controlled by VS Code itself. You should use the right VS Code API instead (check if `ExtensionContext.extensionPath` is what you are looking for, https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#ExtensionContext).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeah, I know what the process is here. I can change my code to use extensionpath. but I couldn't change the library's code. (to change process.cwd() to extension path for example)

Comment: What kind of library are you trying to use? If it sticks to those APIs and is not designed to be for general purposes, I wonder if you should dump it completely to use a fork or another library instead.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I can fork it. But it's going to be hard to maintain it. But before that, I want to do some research on alternative ways. Thanks, Lex for your help

Comment: @LexLi there is nothing wrong with using `console.log` in an extension, you only need to know where to look for the output. You can also opt to use Log Points (Breakpoints) no need to add code you have to remove later, and it also uses `console.log` but the results are shown at a different place

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of changes, I couldn't find something better than changing code by webpack plugins. I changed all of the `process.cwd()` with `extensionpath` by adding this code to the plugins part `webpack.config.js` file

```
      {
        apply(compiler) {
          compiler.hooks.thisCompilation.tap("Replace", (compilation) => {
            compilation.hooks.processAssets.tap(
              {
                name: "TEST_PLUGIN",
                stage: Compilation.PROCESS_ASSETS_STAGE_ADDITIONAL,
              },
              (assets) => {
                //find specific file from assets or iterate through to update each asset
                let filelist = Object.entries(assets);

                //give specific file name
                const fileContent = compilation.getAsset("extension.js");
                const newFileContent =
                  fileContent.source.source().replaceAll("process.cwd()", "extensionpath");
                compilation.updateAsset(
                  "extension.js",
                  new sources.RawSource(newFileContent)
                );
              }
            );
          });
        },
      },
```